# Using an action listener for java to exit a program when a Jmenu button is pressed

Tags: java

I'm attempting to exit a program when the user hits the exit JMenu item.

This is the class I'm using to execute the action listener:

```
public abstract class ExitListener implements ActionListener {
    public void exit(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("exit")) {
            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "Quit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I initialised my button:

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
gameMenu = new JMenu("Game");
this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
menuBar.add(gameMenu);

// Creates the tabs for the Game menu and add's it to the game menu
exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
gameMenu.add(exit);
```

When I select the exit button on the menu, nothing happens.

Comment: You forgot to explain where you were stuck :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `JMenuItem#addActionListener`

`exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());`

There is also an error within `ExitListener`.

The overridden method should be called `actionPerformed`, not `exit`. This will cause a compilation error.

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

An easier way would be to use an anonymous class or even a lambda expression since you only going to use the `ExitListener` once I guess.

```
exit.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("exit")){
           int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "Quit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
        }
});
```